# How to correctly use Jackson @JSONView to exclude specific properties from default serialization?

Tags: jackson

Given a JSON-mapped class like this:

```
public class Person {
    @JsonProperty
    String getName() { ... }

    @JsonProperty @JsonView(SpecialView.class)
    String getId() { ... }
}
```

I need to include only the `name` property when when using "normal" serialization (ie, no view specified), and include both properties when serializing using `SpecialView`. But when I do

```
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(object)
```

(ie, not specifying *any* view), the `id` property is included.

If I do

```
objectMapper..writerWithView(Object.class).writeValueAsString(object)
```

then it behaves as expected. Problem is, I don't control all the code that's doing serialization so I can't force it all to specify a view.

When I stepped through the Jackson source code (v 2.5.4), I see that `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ser.std.BeanSerializerBase.serializeFields()` does not use the `_filteredProps` if there is no "active view":

```
    if (_filteredProps != null && provider.getActiveView() != null) {
        props = _filteredProps;
    } else {
        props = _props;
    }
```

It seems strange that serialization would not respect `@JsonView` when no view is specified. Am I missing something?

Is there a way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 15):

I ran across the same problem. It seems like Jackson totally ignores @JsonView annotations unless a view is specified. To get the behaviour you are after give your mapper a default view of Object.class.

```
mapper.setConfig(mapper.getSerializationConfig().withView(Object.class));
```

Note that you can also exclude fields without @JsonView annotation's using

```
mapper.configure(MapperFeature.DEFAULT_VIEW_INCLUSION, false);
```

This is with Jackson 2.6.3

Comment: This would be a good solution, but as I said in the question, I don't control the code that creates and configures the `ObjectMapper`