# How to get Jackson to ignore minimal fields for a certain view?

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

So say I have a class

```
class ObjectBeingSerialized {
    String name;
    Date createDate; // this is the field I don't want to show up in the the Full JSON view

    @JsonView(Views.Full)
    AnotherObject anotherObject; 
}
```

When I try to serialize this with the Views.Full JSON view, it will include all these properties in the JSON.

Is there a way to, when serializing with a particular JSON view, to exclude a default property? In this case, I want to make it so the Full JSON view doesn't include createDate but includes name and anotherObject, but the default view includes both name and createDate.

Comment: shouldn't adding `transient` in front of `Date createDate` do the trick?

Comment: @Selim I edited the main post. I also want it so that the minimal serialization includes name and createDate but not the AnotherObject object.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to correctly use Jackson @JSONView to exclude specific properties from default serialization?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31250281/how-to-correctly-use-jackson-jsonview-to-exclude-specific-properties-from-defau)

Comment: Not a duplicate; this question is asking the opposite of that question - can you hide properties with views. As far as I can tell the answer is no, which is disappointing.